# Getting specific values from list of tuple

Tags: list, tuples

```
a=[(12,'John',24000),(13,'George',7000),(14,'Evans',30000)]
```

> From the above list of tuples is (roll no., Name, salary) respectively. Now I want to filter tuples only if salary greater than 20000 . How can I do that?

Comment: Is it Python? If so, please, mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

By List Comprehension:

```
a=[(12,'John',24000),(13,'George',7000),(14,'Evans',30000)]
result=[e for e in a if e[2] > 20000]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for loop` should suffice.

```py
a = [(12,'John',24000),(13,'George',7000),(14,'Evans',30000)]

for roll, name, salary in a:
    if salary > 20000:
        print(name)
```